# How do we implement a custom loss that backpropagates with PyTorch?

Tags: loss-function, pytorch

In a neural network code written in PyTorch, we have defined and used this custom loss, that should replicate the behavior of the Cross Entropy loss:

```
def my_loss(output, target):
    global classes    

    v = torch.empty(batchSize)
    xi = torch.empty(batchSize)

    for j in range(0, batchSize):
        v[j] = 0
        for k in range(0, len(classes)):
            v[j] += math.exp(output[j][k]) 

    for j in range(0, batchSize):
        xi[j] = -math.log( math.exp( output[j][target[j]] ) / v[j] )

    loss = torch.mean(xi)
    print(loss)
    loss.requires_grad = True
    return loss
```

but it doesn't converge to accetable accuracies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use pytorch's implementation of math functions, otherwise, torch does not know how to differentiate them. Replace `math.exp` with `torch.exp`, `math.log` with `torch.log`.

Also, try to use vectorised operations instead of loops as often as you can, because this will be much faster.

Finally, as far as I can see, you are merely reimplementing a log loss in pytorch, any reason why you don't use one that has been implemented by default? (see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) or [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#nllloss))

[EDIT]: If after having removed math operations and implemented a vectorised version of the loss, it still does not converge, here are a few pointers on how to debug it:

- Check that the loss is correct by calculating the value manually and compare it with what the function outputs
- Compute the gradient manually and check that it is the same as the values in `loss.grad`, after running `loss.backward()` (more info [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-print-the-computed-gradient-values-for-a-network/34179))
- Monitor the loss and the gradient after a few iterations to check that everything goes right during the training

Comment: I've changed all the math. functions to torch. calls. Still it does not converge.

Comment: Have you checked that your model converges with the Crossentropy loss provided by pytorch? If not, then the model or the data is in cause, not the loss

Comment: yes, it does converge with the Crossentropy loss provided by pytorch.

Comment: Then reimplement with a vectorised version of your loss and drop the loops

Comment: Sorry, but I'm ignorant on how to do it with Python and PyTorch.

Comment: Here you go https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cross-entropy-loss-implementation/43592

Comment: And please accept the answer to close the topic once you have the loss working ;)

Comment: We've tried this loss:
 loss = torch.mean(torch.sum(- target * F.log_softmax(output, -1), -1))
but it stil does not converge.

Comment: Ok, now it converges very slowly.

Comment: See my updated answer if you still have problems... Also, for the future, try to avoid using custom losses when you can avoid it :)